# javascript save state of check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue where the current state of the checkbox is not being saved. I am new to this and any help would be appreciated. Here's the jQuery code that is partially working.

```
var userCityList = [];
$("#checkboxes").unbind('change').bind('change', function (event) {
    var stateVal = $(':selected', $('#ResidentialLocationStateList')).val();
    var cityID = $(event.target)[0].id;//stores city id
    var cityVal = $(event.target)[0].value;//stores city value

    if ($('#' + cityID).is(':checked')) {
        if (userCityList.length < 5) {
            userCityList.push(cityID);
        }
        else {
            $('#' + cityID).prop('checked', false);
            alert("5 cities have been selected");
            return;
        }
    }//end if

    if (!($("#" + cityID).is(':checked'))) {
        userCityList.pop();
    }
    //console.log(userCityList);

});
```

**LOGIC**

When the user selects a state, a set of cities in checkboxes appear. When a user clicks a checkbox, that particular city is stored in the userCityList array. When the user clicks it again, it deletes it from the array. However, if the user changes the state, those cities are no longer checked, which does not allow one to delete it from the array, if needed.

Any suggestions?

**HTML** code

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Select upto 5 state/city combinations</p>
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-pad-left less-width">
        @*<p>Select upto 5 state/city combinations</p>*@
        <select id="ResidentialLocationStateList" name="ResidentialLocationStateList" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="checkboxes">

    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** Here's the image that goes with this issue.

[image]

So when a few cities are selected and the user decides to change the state from the select element, those cities that were selected prior need to be saved.

**UPDATE**

Here's the AJAX code...

```
    $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").change(function () {
    url = "/ResidentialBuilding/getCityList?state=";
    state = $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").val();
    url = url + state;
    //console.log(url);
    $("#checkboxes").empty();
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            //console.log(value.city);
            id = value.city;
            id = id.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            valCity = value.city;
            valCity = valCity.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            $("#checkboxes").append('<input value="' + valCity + '"' + 'type=' + "'checkbox'" +  'id=' + id + '>' + value.city + '</input><br>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but my recommendation would be to not create redundant data. Instead of trying to maintain a list of checked cities, just iterate the cities that are checked when you need them.

Comment: Will an image help you understand the concept betteR?

Comment: Use a multidimensional array to store both stateID and cityID something like: var userCityList = [];userCityList[stateID] = [cityID1, cityID2];

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern version of `jQuery` I would recommend using `.off` and `.on` and to use `.off` if you really have to.

lso the `.pop()` array method removes the last element but the element just clicked may not always be the one that was added last. And since, the check boxes are added dynamically, the following bind could be made at the very beginning of `DOM ready` and not necessarily in any event handler. Rather than give your checkboxes the same ID which leads to invalid HTML, use a class selector, `.checkboxes`.

Therefore, I would suggest the following code

```
var userCityList = [];
$(document).on("change", ".checkboxes", function() {
    var stateVal = $('#ResidentialLocationStateList').val();
    var cityID = this.id;//stores city id
    var cityVal = this.value;//stores city value
    var finalDiv = $('#final');
    var tempDiv  = $('#othertempdiv');

    if( this.checked ) {
        if( userCityList.length < 5 ) {
            userCityList.push( cityID );
            finalDiv.append( this );
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            alert('5 cities have been selected');
        }
    } else {
        var index = $.inArray( cityID, userCityList );
        if( index > -1 ) {
            userCityList.splice( index, 1 );
            tempDiv.append( this );
        }
    }
});
```

Since you're -- per comments below -- replacing the selected cities each time you select a new state, you would have to have a second div which would hold all the selected cities. Un-checking any of the cities in this final div would move it back; if another state is selected, such a city would be lost.

```
<div id="final"></div>
```

Comment: How do I get it to save though? By that I mean if I change the state from MD to FL, and come back to MD, the cities in MD must be still checked.

Comment: Quite likely I may not have full understood your question. Can you create a jsfiddle or at the least provide sample HTML **as seen by your browser**.

Comment: Yes. Will do right away. **updated please have a look**

Comment: An image, though great for visualizing the look and feel of your page, does not tell much about the underlying **HTML**. Where do the cities come from? Are they created on the fly? Are they already existing on the DOM? That's very important to know if you want to be able to retained their `checked`-ness, if you please :)

Comment: Alright. I will explain. When the user selects a state from the select element, an AJAX call is made to the database to obtain the list of cities. When a state is changed, the div containing the checkboxes is emptied and new cities are added. Does that help?

Comment: As the cities are checked, can you also move them to another -- final -- div so those selected are retained and they are selected. When a new state is selected, the final div still has cities selected from the previously selected state which can be unselected to remove from this final div and the array. **Just a suggestion ... hopefully it makes sense.** :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a multidimensional array to store both state and city IDs, like  **userCityList [ stateVal ]**:

```
var userCityList = [];
$("#checkboxes").unbind('change').bind('change', function (event) {
    var stateVal = $(':selected', $('#ResidentialLocationStateList')).val();
    var cityID = $(event.target)[0].id;//stores city id
    var cityVal = $(event.target)[0].value;//stores city value

    if ($('#' + cityID).is(':checked')) {
        if (userCityList.length < 5) {    
            if(!userCityList[stateVal])userCityList[stateVal] = [];            
            userCityList[stateVal].push(cityID);
        }
        else {
            $('#' + cityID).prop('checked', false);
            alert("5 cities have been selected");
            return;
        }
    }//end if

    if (!($("#" + cityID).is(':checked'))) {
        if(userCityList[stateVal]){
        //Edited, now it can remove the city by its position (index)
          var position = $.inArray(cityID, userCityList[stateVal]);   
            userCityList[stateVal].slice(position, 1);
        }

    }
});
```

So when you need to retrieve the checked cities for an state you can do just:

```
for(var i =0; i < userCityList[stateVal].length; i++){
   console.log(userCityList[stateVal][i]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

The hard work is done. Now, in your ajax code, when you load a new set of checkboxes, you have to check if the checkbox was previously checked:

```
  $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").change(function () {
    url = "/ResidentialBuilding/getCityList?state=";
    state = $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").val();
    url = url + state;
    //console.log(url);
    $("#checkboxes").empty();
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            //console.log(value.city);
            id = value.city;
            id = id.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            valCity = value.city;
            valCity = valCity.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            $("#checkboxes").append('<input value="' + valCity + '"' + 'type=' + "'checkbox'" +  'id=' + id + '>' + value.city + '</input><br>');
            //Let's check if this checkbox was previously checked
            if($.inArray(id, userCityList[state])){
                    //if yes, let's check it again
                    $('#'+id).prop('checked', true);                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that the userCityList variable must be global to store these values and you will loose your checkboxes memories if you refresh the page, of course.

Comment: I tried your code, but the push and pop do not work. It bugs out on those specific lines.

Comment: Ok, you said: "When the user selects a state from the select element, an AJAX call is made to the database to obtain the list of cities. When a state is changed, the div containing the checkboxes is emptied and new cities are added..." just after new cities been added, foreach city, check if your cityID is in your userCityList[stateVal] array. If yes, apply prop('checked', true) in the current city/checkbox...